# Teradata DDL with Date Formatting

Tags: date-format, ddl, teradata

I wanna create a table in teradata with YYYY-MM format and give default value as '0001-01'. Is it possible to do both?..However i am able to do this..

create table test(t1 date format 'yyyy-mm' not null);

Answer (score 1):

Both are working perfectly.

See  below for syntax.

```
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
ct t1(x1 int,y1 date format 'yyyy-mm' not null default date '0001-01-01');

ct t1(x1 int,y1 date format 'yyyy-mm' not null default date '0001-01-01');

 *** Table has been created.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
ins t1(1,'2011-11');

ins t1(1,'2011-11');

 *** Insert completed. One row added.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
ins t1(2,);

ins t1(2,);

 *** Insert completed. One row added.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
sel * from t1;

sel * from t1;

*** Query completed. 2 rows found. 2 columns returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

         x1       y1
 -----------  -------
          1  2011-11
          2  0001-01
```

Comment: Default values are permitted on DATE columns.

Comment: Thanks Rob, just give me an example..I'll agree with you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored internally as `INTEGER` values in Teradata. You will have to specify your `DEFAULT` as `DATE '0001-01-01'` and allow the `FORMAT` clause to return the formated data to the client. This also means you will have to load your data as valid dates and not 'yyyy-mm' values.

EDIT:

```
/* Test results in Teradata Studio 14.2 via JDBC connection to Teradata 13.10 */

create table MyDB.MyTable
  (x1 date format 'yyyy-mm' not null default date '0001-01-01');

insert into MyDB.MyTable values (date '2013-01-01'); -- Succeeds
insert into MyDB.MyTable values ('2013-02'); -- Fails
insert into MyDB.MyTable values (date '2013-02'); -- Fails

select * from cms_work_comm_prd.t5; -- Returns to Teradata Studio (JDBC): 2013-01-01
```

Comment: which means i have to store them as char and not as date?

Comment: Added example based on tests in Teradata 13.10 via Teradata Studio 14.2

Comment: Great, congrats Anantha, you got solution to both your problems..!!